# Ajax call to webapi does not hit the ajax response and not returning results

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-ajax

I have a webapi project where I'm returning a list of products and I have an ajax call on my another project.

When I use ajax call on webapi index page it gets the response, while when I'm using it on the project that references webapi, it doesn't hit the ajax's response bit.

In both cases the api `Get` method is called and returns correct results and response, it's just ajax doesn't exceute on the other project.

The ajax code is exactly the same on both webapi index page as it is on the other project page:

Ajax:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:65331/dataapi/Product")
    .done(function (data) {
        // On the other project it never gets to this bit below:
        $.each(data, function (item) {
            var label = item.Name + ' (' + item.Code + ')';
        });
    });
```

WebAPI get method:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        ProductSearcher searcher = new ProductSearcher();
        List<ProductModel> products = searcher.GetResults();

        // Then I return the list
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, products);
    }
```

I tried also to use `$.ajax({type: "GET", ...})` but it doesn't change anything.

Any ideas why how can I get the ajax response working?

Comment: Please share the contract of Results operation of ProductSearcher.

Comment: It's a list of ProductModel and it's returning correct List results @sette

Comment: When you want to make ajax request from a different project, did you enable CORS on the webapi?